# The SelectedItem of DataGrid in WPF does not fire if I switch from one ComboBox with IsEditable="True" to another

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem

In WPF I have a `DataGrid`. I am using MVVM.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedRows}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
```

If I change row then the setter of the `SelectedRow` runs as it should.

There is one exception.
One of the columns is a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which contains `ComboBox` with `IsEditable="True"`

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryEditingTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.AppData.CategoryObjects}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Category, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="FullName" IsEditable="True">
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

If I start to edit the content of the `ComboBox` then I click to another editable `ComboBox` in another row then the setter of the `SelectedRow` does not run. I can edit the content of the second `ComboBox` with keyboard. If I click to another cell in the same row then the system realizes that the row has changed and the setter starts. I want the setter to run as soon as I leave a row.

**Update 1**

Editing mode of a `ComboBox` in a `DataGrid`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The input control (`ComboBox`) steals the focus which prevents the `DataGrid` control from actually selecting the row.

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the input control to overcome this:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) =>
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).DataContext;
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryEditingTemplate">
    <ComboBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ItemsSource ...
```

Comment: Thank you  @mm8 I tried your suggestion. If I click to the text of the `ComboBox` then the function does not run. I go directly to editing mode, and I still can click into the text of another `ComboBox`.

Comment: Directly to editing mode? What does that mean? Is there a `ComboBox` in the `CellTemplate` as well? You need to handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` of this one as well then.

Comment: Hi @mm8, On editing mode I mean when I click to the `ComboBox` and its content is selected, and I can change the text with keyboard (I add an image to the question). For the time being I use the same ˙DataTemplate` for `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. What is interesting if I add `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to the `DataGrid` itself then this event fires as it should.

Comment: It fires when you click on the `ComboBox`.

Comment: `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` should fire when I click the `ComboBox` but it does not, instead the `ComboBox` goes into editing mode. If I now select the same `ComboBox` again then `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` fires. (quite strange)

Comment: Isn't it in edit mode in the first place? You need to handle the event for all `ComboBoxes`.

Comment: The `IsEditable` property is always true. At the beginning nothing is selected in the `DataGrid`. I click to the `ComboBox`, the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` does not fire, but the text in the `ComboBox` is selected (that what I call edit mode). If I click to another `ComboBox` then the event still not fire.

Comment: Then you and I are doing something differently. Please provide a repo of your issue including a detailed description of how to run it.

Comment: Dear @mm8!  I created a repo and a small video explaining what I want.  [repo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovui08gzoafh4a1/EventHandler.zip?dl=0), [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq59wkys4xuo7nj/problem.mkv?dl=0)

Comment: Dear @mm8! Did you have a chance to look at the code?

Comment: Hi @mm8! Did you have a chance to look at the code?

Comment: No. Where should I look? Please edit your question to include a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: Hi again! The code and a short video is linked at my comment sent at Oct 9.